# Who program this microcontroller?

Tags: arduino, isp

I'm looking at [this ISP programmer](http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/) for the Atmega chips. I don't understand how the programmer's program is loaded. Is this chip programmed by the computer, or does it need to be pre-programmed?

Is my guess correct? Can I buy the needed 'naked' chip anywhere?

Comment: reason for downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the shop link, you posted, you will notice that the chip in the kit is preprogrammed.

You will have only to assemble the kit, and is supposed to be compatible with the AVRStudio, from there you can connect with any chip AVR8 respecting the standard Atmel ISP

Answer (score 1):

It's right there on the page:

> You can build this design using the schematic and firmware, or buy a kit from the Adafruit webshop. Having a full kit available solves the "chicken & egg" problem of purchasing or building a USB programmer that then needs a programmer of some sort to 'kick start'.

The chip inside does need to be programmed and if you don't already have a programmer you can just purchase the [complete kit](http://www.adafruit.com/products/46) from Adafruit.